USD-barcode-scanner not recognizing the number 3 or #
I have a usb scanner (huawei Model HC-P10) connected to a raspberry PI. I use it to pick up qrcode scans, all the scans work but the number 3 is not being recognized when scanned. The raw data shows that 'KEY_MOD_RSHIFT' which is 0x20.
Dont know if the scanner itself is the issue.
The previous hid_reports file didn't have the numeber 3 assigned, I have assigned it 0x1g.
the previous nid_reports file had 3 assiged to 0x20 which was the same as 'KEY_MOD_RSHIFT', I updated it to 0x1g.
The problem is persisting, even for # the output is 0x20.
I dont know where else I can make changes.
I am using node-hid.
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("hid_report.json");
let hid = JSON.parse(rawdata);

The parsed data is all correct but the scan coming from the qrcode is not updated its ids.
It seems as if 3/# and right shift are linked or by default its using 0x20.
raw <Buffer 00 00 0b 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 0b
HID value: h
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 17 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 17
HID value: t
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 17 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 17
HID value: t
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 13 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 13
HID value: p
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 16 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 16
HID value: s
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 20 00 33 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 20
HID value: KEY_MOD_RSHIFT
ID 33
HID value: ;
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 38 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 38
HID value: /
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 38 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 38
HID value: /
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 1a 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 1a
HID value: w
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 1a 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 1a
HID value: w
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 1a 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 1a
HID value: w
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 37 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 37
HID value: .
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 07
HID value: d
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 12
HID value: o
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 12
HID value: o
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 13 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 13
HID value: p
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 08
HID value: e
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 08
HID value: e
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 07
HID value: d
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 12
HID value: o
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 12
HID value: o
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 37 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 37
HID value: .
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 06
HID value: c
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 12
HID value: o
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 10
HID value: m
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 38 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 38
HID value: /
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 19 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 19
HID value: v
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 08
HID value: e
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 11 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 11
HID value: n
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 18 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 18
HID value: u
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 08
HID value: e
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 20 00 2d 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 20
HID value: KEY_MOD_RSHIFT
ID 2d
HID value: -
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 0f 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 0f
HID value: l
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 12
HID value: o
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 1c 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 1c
HID value: y
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 04
HID value: a
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 0f 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 0f
HID value: l
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 17 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 17
HID value: t
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 1c 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 1c
HID value: y
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 20 00 2d 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 20
HID value: KEY_MOD_RSHIFT
ID 2d
HID value: -
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 06
HID value: c
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 04
HID value: a
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 15 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 15
HID value: r
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 07
HID value: d
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 38 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 38
HID value: /
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 20
HID value: KEY_MOD_RSHIFT
raw <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
raw <Buffer 00 00 28 00 00 00 00 00>
ID 28
HID value: KEY_ENTER

This is the raw data from a scan the user-id is 3.
https://www.doopeedoo.com/venue_loyalty_card/3

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Given that the USB HID usage code for the 3 key is 0x20 and that 0x20 is also the ASCII code for a space character, my guess is that you may not be parsing the data from the device correctly. It may help to post more information about what the raw data looks like and the code you are using to process it.
